# Removing n first digits on a field attribute table using QGIS string functions

Tags: qgis, string, function

I'm looking for a QGIS function to remove the first n digits on a field attribute table using QGIS string function.
For exemple I have the following string in a QGIS attribute table:

> 742-004-SRV Superficie : 12780

My aim is to remove the first 12 characters. How to achieve this with QGIS?

Comment: So you want to turn `742-004-SRV Superficie : 12780` into `Superficie : 12780?`

Comment: Hi Joseph, yes exactly!

Answer (score 5):

You can use substr.

So:

```
substr(  "Field" , 13,  length( "Field"))
```

So this grabs everything from the 13th to the Nth character, with the Nth being the lenght of the field.

Comment: Nicely done! Can also use `right( "field",  length("field" ) - 12)` which is essentially the same :)

Comment: Have you actually tested this? Looking at the definition of substr in QGIS, the parameters are input_string, startpos, and length (integer representing length of string to extract). So the last parameter should be length("Field") - 13 + 1

Comment: @TJRockefeller - Hmm, [QGIS disagrees](http://imgur.com/a/f4T5g) :)

Comment: @Joseph either I'm blind (more likely) or you changed your comment. I didn't see you were doing length - 12 for some reason I thought it was just 12.

Comment: @TJRockefeller - No problem (FYI, if someone changes their comment, you can see a pencil icon next to it which can tell you how many times the comment has been edited). Like this :)

Comment: I tested this, and it does work, but only because of how it is evaluated. It also works to do `substr("Field", 13, 999999999)` In other languages like C# this will give you an out of range exception, so at some point QGIS may "fix" this, and it won't work as written.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing me out through the right function. My issue has been successfully resolved...I've been able to remove from my table the string I don't need. Thank again to Joseph and TJ Rockefeller.